# One or multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, polymorphic-associations, single-table-inheritance

I have different kinds of measurements. They are not related to each other. Let’s say `A`, `B`, and `C`. All three of them have the same structure, `ID (integer)`, `value (float)`, `experiment_id (integer)` (relation to an experiments table).

I do not know the best way to store this information.

A) Is it better to use three tables (`A`, `B`, and `C`)?

B) Or is it better to store all of them in one table called `measurements` and add an additional column called `measurement_type` to store the information of `A`, `B`, or `C` (including indexes).

In my application I would like to have three Models called `A`, `B`, and `C`.

The solution should be fast, because for each measurement type, there might be hundreds of million, or even billion entries one day. Furthermore, one day there might be measurement type `D`, `E`, `...`, `Z`.

By the way, I am using an Oracle Enterprise database.

Comment: How do you intend to query the data? Also, is there any intrinsic meaning to the `ID`? For example, does it need to be unique _across_ `A`, `B` and `C`? Does it have to correspond to the order in which the measurements were taken? Also, are all measurements `float`?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic The `ID` is nothing special. The best thing is to ignore it :-). The order is not important. And all measurements are `float`.

Comment: How do you mean to distinguish between two measurements that happen to have the same `value`? And please answer my other question: How do you intend to query the data?

Comment: I have not only the relation to experiments. The complete structure includes `experiment_id` and `feature_id`. The combination of experiment and feature is unique. In one experiment are many features having each one value. It can be that one value occurs more than one time.
I am going to query for all values that belong to one experiment. Or all values that belong to one feature (multiple experiments).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments, and assuming you focus is on query performance (as opposed to INSERT performance), looks like you need a model similar to this:

[image]

Use [`ORGANIZATION INDEX`](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index) on `MEASUREMENT` table (also consider using `COMPRESS` clause, since there will be many rows sharing the same leading `EXPERIMENT_ID`).

The index `I1` consist from: `{FEATURE_ID, EXPERIMENT_ID, MEASUREMENT_TYPE, VALUE}`, in that order. Consider using `COMPRESS` clause, since there will be many rows sharing the same leading `FEATURE_ID`).

This gives us 2 B-Trees:

1. The B-Tree "underneath" the `PK`, i.e. the index-organized table itself.
2. The B-Tree "underneath" the index `I1`.

A query on `EXPERIMENT_ID` can be satisfied by a single index range scan in the `PK` B-Tree and **no** table heap access (heap doesn't exist). The `PK` B-Tree naturally stores the rows belonging to the **same experiment** physically close together, so I/O is minimized.

A query on `FEATURE_ID` can also be satisfied by a single range scan (in the `I1` B-Tree). The `I1` is a [covering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/glossary/covering-index) index, so there is no need to do a double-lookup into the `PK` B-Tree. The `I1` B-Tree naturally stores the rows belonging to the **same feature** physically close together, so I/O is minimized.

I'd shy away from horizontally partitioning the `MEASUREMENT` table on `MEASUREMENT_TYPE`, unless you have performed measurements on representative amounts of data and concluded it provides a performance tradeoff that better suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Since the measurement types can grow and not restricted to A, B and C, it is recommended to use option B) as it supports additional measurement types when needed.